# Unable to save text file using while loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

it saving a text file but the file was empty please help me, I think the error happen in the while loop?
I already try for loop but it result in infinite loop

```
with open('F:\\datamining\\Textmining\\Coded\\newlist.txt') as fp:
    
    line  = fp.readline()
    cnt=1
    f=open('F:\\datamining\\Textmining\\Coded\\Lastlist.txt','w')
    while line:
        data=line.strip()
        if data in words :
            print(data)
            f.write(data+"\n")
        line=fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you should close the second file after writing. That can be done either with `f.close()` at the end of the writing loop, or with another indented context manager, that closes the file when exiting.

Solution with `f.close()`:

```py
with open('F:\\datamining\\Textmining\\Coded\\newlist.txt') as fp:
    
    line  = fp.readline()
    cnt=1
    f=open('F:\\datamining\\Textmining\\Coded\\Lastlist.txt','w') as f:
    while line:
        data=line.strip()
        if data in words :
            print(data)
            f.write(data+"\n")
        line=fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
    f.close()
```

Solution with the context manager:

```py
with open('F:\\datamining\\Textmining\\Coded\\newlist.txt') as fp:
    
    line  = fp.readline()
    cnt=1
    with open('F:\\datamining\\Textmining\\Coded\\Lastlist.txt','w') as f:
        while line:
            data=line.strip()
            if data in words :
                print(data)
                f.write(data+"\n")
            line=fp.readline()
            cnt += 1
```

Comment: still doesn't write the text file

Comment: It might be that the check `if data in words` is failing. Is the print showing something? Or the other thing that you can try is to issue an `f.flush()` before closing.